# How do I change JAXB implementations?

Tags: java, jaxb, annotations

How can I change out the default JAXB implementation for another one?  I'm running Java 1.7.

Comment: (Wait .. there is more than one? :-/)

Comment: Dint get your question. But is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002006/how-to-specify-a-particular-jaxb-implementation) you are looking for?

Comment: It looks like it may be.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must place a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with contents like the following that specifies EclipseLink MOXy as the JAXB (JSR-222) provider (I'm the MOXy lead).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html