# Error deploying JAXWS webservice on Websphere server

Tags: web-services, websphere, jax-ws

I am deploying JAX-WS webservice on websphere and when I am testing the same through soapUI, it is throwing below error. Please advice what can be the issue:

```
ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl incompatible with com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
```

Note: I have chanaged the classloader setting in websphere from parent first to parent last as well.

following are the jars in my war file.

**jaxb-api-2.2.6.jar**

**jaxb-impl-2.2.5.jar**

**jaxb-xjc-2.1.9.jar**

**jaxws-api-2.1.jar**

**jaxws-maven-plugin-1.11.jar**

**jaxws-rt-2.1.5.jar**

**jaxws-tools-2.1.5.jar**

Please advice what can be the issue? is it a common problem??

Answer (score 4):

IBM WebSphere comes out with its own JAX-WS implementation. If you intend to use third-party JAX-WS provider, try to disable the default one, either by adding property DisableIBMJAXWSEngine: true into Manifest file, or by adding the following JVM property:

```
com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true
```

Reference links:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/xrun_jvm.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-16-5-474&lang=en

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK96989

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following in the code. I use WAS 8.5.5 with IBM JDK 1.6. Hope this help.

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext", "com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory");
```