# Changing jax-b implementation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

my websphere uses some IBM propertiary jaxb implementation which is not compatible with something I'm using. I included the one I'd like to use in the classpath but the application uses still the default one. I've read that I can change the implementation by:

1. Creating a file called jaxb.properties where my domain jax-b annotated classes reside in which contains something like

   javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl

The problem with this approach is that those classes are outside the project I'm developing.

2. Creating a file javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext just like in http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html in *Discovery of JAXB implementation* chapter. The problem is I can't figure out what should be inside of it and have no easy way to test it. Can anyone tell me what *standard service descriptor convention* is? How this file should look like if I'd like to use com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl as the implementation of jaxb?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you already seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19731784/3364187) answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. That's the first option :)

Answer (score 1):

The first option itself would do.

> The problem with this approach is that those classes are outside the
>   project I'm developing.

This is not a problem - even though the domain classes reside inside a library/ jar, you still can have the package structure + jaxb.properties created in the classpath. i.e. If it's a maven project, you can create this `package` structure in resources directory.