# Eclipse 4.12 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I am getting the error below while running my eclipse plugin.
Eclipse used 4.12 with java11. It used to work fine in eclipse 4.6.3 + java8.

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory not found
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory cannot be found by com.my.cep.studio.cluster.topology_0.0.0]

!ENTRY com.my.cep.diagramming 4 0   at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:146)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:289)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375)
    at com.my.cep.studio.cluster.topology.editors.ClusterTopologyDiagramManager.parseFile(ClusterTopologyDiagramManager.java:193)
    at com.my.cep.studio.cluster.topology.editors.ClusterTopologyDiagramManager.openModel(ClusterTopologyDiagramManager.java:175)
    at com.my.cep.diagramming.drawing.BaseDiagramManager.createDrawingCanvas(BaseDiagramManager.java:233)
    at com.my.cep.diagramming.drawing.DiagramManager$2.run(DiagramManager.java:259)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory cannot be found by com.my.cep.studio.cluster.topology_0.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.safeLoadClass(ContextFinder.java:480)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:112)
```

Comment: A plug-in that you have installed into Eclipse (`com.my.cep.studio`?) makes use of JAXB, which is contained in Java 8, but not in Java 11. [Running Eclipse with Java 8](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) should fix your issue (you can still use Java 11 for your projects in Eclipse).

Comment: @howler com.my.cep.studio is my custom writen plugin. The exception occurs from eclipse internal plugin "javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar". This is same as jaxb jar and same code inside. The exception occurs from class ContextFinder find method at line  return newInstance(contextPath, contextPathClasses, PLATFORM_DEFAULT_FACTORY_CLASS, classLoader, properties). Here PLATFORM_DEFAULT_FACTORY_CLASS points to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

Comment: The Eclipse platform does not require or contain the JAXB plug-in (only some Eclipse IDE packages contain the `javax.xml.bind` plug-in). Probably a plug-in/bundle is missing in your dependencies. Show how `javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder` is included, and find out which missing plug-in contains `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory`.

Comment: All you need to go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204141/replacements-for-deprecated-jpms-modules-with-java-ee-apis/48204154#48204154

Answer (score 68):

Sun people have remove directly access to jaxb package in java 11.
These dependency will work instead of it. Same fix if you are facing hibernate `NullPointerException` issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In case anyone struggles to find out why dependencies themselves did not help - make sure to check the imports. The code I worked on used old javax.xml.bind imports - when changed to jakarta.xml.bind the exception has gone.

Answer (score 14):

I've stumbled upon this question while migrating a [big ancient Java application](https://github.com/Rothamsted/ondex-knet-builder) to Java 11. I think the following might come useful.

I had everything in place in my Maven POMs, javax bindings, JAXB's implementation, a few tests working fine. Yet, the original application's tests kept inexplicably complaining that `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory` is not found.

Indeed, that class isn't in any 3rd-party implementations of JAXB (I'm using the Glassfish's one, but there are several others), and one has to replace the default factory that is instantiated inside  `javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance( <classes> )` with some new implementation (`com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory` in my case and, I guess, in other JAXB libs too).

And well, one of the ways to set that is via the `jaxb.properties` file, which must be visible to the classpath (so, in Maven, it's usually somewhere like `src/main/resources/*`). As it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731784/529286), this file has to contain:

```java
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.JAXBContextFactory
```

In my case, it was containing the old now-disappeared factory. I guess, current JAXB libraries use a correct default factory if they don't meet that file, however it might be already present in your codebase and you might need a while before realising it. I hope that this answer will save you the time I wasted.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you are using features in javax that existed in java 8 but are removed in Java 11

see this answer 
[How to resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Answer (score 5):

These libs worked for me (inspired by Vivek's response above). When I tried using [JAXB sample from Vogella tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html) with Intellij.

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'org.eclipse.persistence.moxy',version: '2.7.3'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1'
    compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.25.0-GA'
}
```

Comment: compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1' and 
    compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.1' solved the problem

Answer (score 5):

For me, these 2 lines in the **build.gradle** worked for me.

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

I was strugling  with the same problem. The **jakarta.xml.bind** implementation will want to use the **com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory** instead of **com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory** which is available in the **com.sun.xml.bind**. So that combo worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Adding these dependancies in my pom solved the issue

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to create and add the following file in my project 
`META-INF/services/javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext`
 with the following content:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

[image]

This tells the API which implementation to use.

I was using the following runtime implementation:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```