# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap" is not supported

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, cxf, apache-karaf

I am running my application in Apache Karaf and we are using Apache CXF 2.7.6, JAXB api version 2.2 and JDK is 1.7.0_80. And while installing our application in karaf, we get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-71" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBean': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:371)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:338)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:446)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:204)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:159)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:456)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap" is not supported]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:237)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:396)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:327)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:327)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:228)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:479)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:336)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap" is not supported
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:222)
    ... 42 more
```

could you please let me know what could be done here to solve this issue? Any help in this regard is very much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qbbg.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.defaultNamespaceRemap` instead.

You're probably using JAXB RI packaged with JDK, not standalone. That JAXB package gets "repackaged" from `com.sun.xml.bind` to `com.sun.xml.internal.bind`. Probably they also change the constant during repackaging. How cool.

[image: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext]

Comment: Thanks Lexicore for your comment. I had a look at this file which is inside a jar in my .m2 repo directory.  C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2\jaxb-impl-2.2.jar. So, how do you propose to edit this file. It is a class file already bundled and available in maven repo. I could not understand how to apply your suggestion. I mean in my source code, there is no mention of this property. It is purely a dependency that my code uses. Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Probably the best option would be to use JAXB RI you provide. For this you will need to configure exactly which JAXB RI should be used. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002848/303810

Comment: Thank you very much @lexicore. Your approach to use lib/endorsed directory did work.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the centos user all the permissions for `karaf` directory and modified the `.bash_profile` file to contain JAVA_HOME and added karaf and maven to the PATH. Also, modified the run function in the `karaf-client` file located in karaf bin directory to contain the following:

```
JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/endorsed:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/endorsed:${KARAF_HOME}/lib/endorsed"

exec "$JAVA" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.endorsed.dirs="${JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS}" -Djava.ext.dirs="${JAVA_EXT_DIRS}" -Dkaraf.instances="${KARAF_HOME}/instances" -Dkaraf.home="$KARAF_HOME" -Dkaraf.base="$KARAF_BASE" -Djava.io.tmpdir="$KARAF_DATA/tmp" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="$KARAF_BASE/etc/java.util.logging.properties" $KARAF_OPTS $OPTS -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.apache.karaf.client.Main "$@"
```

Important reference link for lib/endorsed approach:

https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Migrating_JAXB_2_0_applications_to_JavaSE_6.html

[How to specify a particular JAXB implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002006/how-to-specify-a-particular-jaxb-implementation/10002848#10002848)